# BSoD при изменении положения экрана у ноутбука

Tags: windows, железо, asus, bsod

у меня наблюдается следующая неприятная проблема. При работе на ноутбуке, с некоторой (неопределённой) переодичностью, при изменении положения экрана (приподнимаю, немного опускаю) появляется BSoD. При чём очень часто вместо текста, с (кодом ошибки) на экране белые полосы, так-же именно в этих случаях дамп памяти не создаётся, хотя я настроил его создание. Изначально я думал что проблема в контакте между экраном и ноутбуком. Но когда при запуске я двигаю экран, ничего не происходит, ОС спокойно начинает работать.

Самое интересное что когда я впервые с этим столкнулся, 2-3 месяца назад, BSoD появлялся, вообще от любого касания к экрану. Проблема решилась когда я запустил Debian Installer и просто погулял по менюшкам, т.е установку я так и не произвёл.

Ноутбук: ASUS X542UA, Win8.1, MemTest86+ прогонял с RAM всё нормально, HDD в порядке.

P. S. Ответы в стиле "Поставь *nix, и всё будет нормально." не принимаются, так-как ноутбук не мой, а ОС попросили сохранить.

Answer (score 1):

Звучит так, будто проблема все же со шлейфом: когда экран приподнимается -- шлейф натягивается и теряется контакт. Из-за этого в системе пропадает устройство, а потом, возможно, сразу же появляется снова. Где-то на этом этапе (идентификации нового устройства / отправке видеоданных) возникает критическая ошибка. Могу допустить, что во время загрузки винды такое событие не вызывает критическую ошибку.
Если не боишься разобрать ноутбук -- попробуй его переподключить и убедись, что зажим держится.